# regex for validating ip-range from ip-list

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have regex for validating list of 50 ips comma-separated:

```
^(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:,? ?)){1,50}$
```

list example:

```
10.10.10.1,127.0.0.1
```

now i need to support list, like this:

```
10.10.10.1,127.0.0.1-127.0.0.125
```

i try, to use subpatterns, but nothing happened

can somebody provide regex example for validating this string:

```
127.0.0.1-127.0.0.125
```

Comment: Can a `,` or `-` appear at the start of the string? Your current approach allows that.

Comment: What about `::1` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, your answer is correct!

Comment: @CD001 what do you mean?

Comment: You're only validating IPv4 addresses, not their IPv6 equivalents. `::1` is equivalent to `127.0.0.1`. Just curious is all.

Comment: @CD001 we are using only IPv4 for now)

Comment: Do you care about invalid ranges? `127.0.0.1-126.0.0.125`?

Comment: @chris85 before your message - no. But now - yes :D

Comment: I think that's going to be pretty difficult with regex. I'd use a CSV parser, then explode on `-`s and compare the values with `ip2long` if the end is less then the start throw error.

Comment: @chris85, i also think, that i can validate string format with this regex, and in controller, or form validate ranges individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use 2 things here: use the negated character class to match either `,` or `-`, and use a subrouting call to make sure your pattern stays of a reasonable size and the string cannot start with `,` or `-`:

```
^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?:[,-](?1)){0,49}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dg92i/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))` - Group 1 capturing 1 IP address
- `(?:[,-](?1)){0,49}` - 0 to 49 (as the subpattern above already matched 1 IP, it will sum up to 50 all in all) sequences of:

  - `[,-]` - a character class matching either `,`or `-`
  - `(?1)` - the subroutine call that "repeats" Group 1 subpattern (unlike the backreference that matches the same *value* captured with a capturing group)
- `$` - end of string