# Add an additional condition to RFC 5322 Email Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, rfc5322

I took this regex from a top rated Stackoverflow answer to make the mails RFC 5322 compliant and it seems to work fine.

```
const re = /^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/;
return re.test('abcd@gmail.co+m')
```

I would also like to negate the occurrence of **+** at any section of the string. Where should i make the change

Comment: A negative lookahead after `^` will do that. Just as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/3832970). Remember to escape `+` since it is a special char.

Comment: Not sure where to place that.. At the start of regex?

Comment: See my comment, see the linked post.

Comment: Well I'm not very good at regex, reason I asked here

Comment: It is fine, just negating regex result is a very broad and well-covered topic on SO.

Comment: Can you please paste the updated regex pattern, If you don't mind

Comment: `^(?!.*\+)...your pattern here....`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew email@111.222.333.44444 seems to be valid as per this regex.
Its listed invalid here http://onlinetraining.etestinghub.com/email-validation-test-cases/. Can we handle it in the same regex?

Comment: Why is it invalid?

Comment: The QA team wants to validate the IP range as well

Comment: Then use `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` instead of some `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}`. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40847675/3832970).